# How can I get fields in an original order?

Tags: python, django, introspection

I have a code like:

```
class Ordered(object):
    x = 0
    z = 0
    b = 0
    a = 0

print(dir(Ordered))
```

it prints:

```
[ ......., a, b, x, z]
```

How can I get fields in an original order: x, z, b, a?
I've seen similar behavior in Django Models.

Comment: Methods, properties etc. are stored as dictionaries within objects, and dictionaries are by definition unordered. What are you trying to achieve (or better, why)?

Comment: You need Python 3 to do this without hacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4460565/821378

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned above, if you want to keep things simple, just use a eg `_ordering` attribute, which manually keeps track of ordering. Otherwise, here is a metaclass approach (like the one Django uses), which creates an ordering attribute automatically.

**Recording the original ordering**

Classes don't keep track of the ordering of the attributes. You can however keep track of which order the field instances were created. For that, you'll have to use your own class for fields (not int). The class keeps track of how many instances have already been made and each instance takes note of its position. Here is how you would do it for your example (storing integers):

```
class MyOrderedField(int):
  creation_counter = 0

  def __init__(self, val):
    # Set the instance's counter, to keep track of ordering
    self.creation_counter = MyOrderedField.creation_counter
    # Increment the class's counter for future instances
    MyOrderedField.creation_counter += 1
```

**Creating an `ordered_items` attribute automatically**

Now that your fields have a number which can be used to order them, your parent class needs to use that somehow. You can do this a variety of ways, if I remember correctly, Django uses Metaclasses to do this, which is a bit wild for a simple class.

```
class BaseWithOrderedFields(type):
  """ Metaclass, which provides an attribute "ordered_fields", being an ordered
      list of class attributes that have a "creation_counter" attribute. """

  def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
    new_class = super(BaseWithOrderedFields, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
    # Add an attribute to access ordered, orderable fields
    new_class._ordered_items = [(name, attrs.pop(name)) for name, obj in attrs.items()
                                    if hasattr(obj, "creation_counter")]
    new_class._ordered_items.sort(key=lambda item: item[1].creation_counter)
    return new_class
```

**Using this metaclass**

So, how do you use this? First, you need to use our new `MyOrderedField` class when defining your attributes. This new class will keep track of the order in which the fields were created:

```
class Ordered(object):
  __metaclass__ = BaseWithOrderedFields

  x = MyOrderedField(0)
  z = MyOrderedField(0)
  b = MyOrderedField(0)
  a = MyOrderedField(0)
```

Then you can access the ordered fields in our automatically created attribute `ordered_fields`:

```
>>> ordered = Ordered()
>>> ordered.ordered_fields
[('x', 0), ('z', 0), ('b', 0), ('a', 0)]
```

Feel free to change this to an ordered dict or just return the names or whatever you need. Additionally, you can define an empty class with the `__metaclass__` and inherit from there.

**Don't use this!**

As you can see, this approach is a little overcomplicated and probably not suitable for most tasks or python developers. If you're newish to python, you'll probably spend more time and effort developing your metaclass than you would have if you just defined the ordering manually. Defining your own ordering manually is almost always going to be the best approach. Django do it automatically because the complicated code is hidden from the end developer, and Django is used far more often than it itself is written/maintained. So only if you're developing a framework for other developers, then metaclasses may be useful for you.

Comment: I develop framework for traders and your solution that is what I need. I wish to simplify declaring of input and output parameters for indicators, and I really use instances as fields. With "int" I have too simplified an example))) Thank you for the best answer! :)

Comment: WARNING! This version of __new__ don't get fields from bases. Therefore subclasses lose parent's ordered fields! Add they if needed.

Answer (score 5):

I was 80% done with this answer when Will posted his, but I decided to post anyway so the effort wouldn't go to waste (our answers basically describe the same thing).

Here's how Django does it. I've chosen to keep the same nomenclature, methodology, and data structures as Django, so that this answer may be also useful for people trying to understand how field names are sorted in Django.

```
from bisect import bisect

class Field(object):
    # A global creation counter that will contain the number of Field objects
    # created globally.
    creation_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Field, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Store the creation index in the "creation_counter" of the field.
        self.creation_counter = Field.creation_counter
        # Increment the global counter.
        Field.creation_counter += 1
        # As with Django, we'll be storing the name of the model property
        # that holds this field in "name".
        self.name = None

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        # This specifies that fields should be compared based on their creation
        # counters, allowing sorted lists to be built using bisect.
        return cmp(self.creation_counter, other.creation_counter)

# A metaclass used by all Models
class ModelBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        klass = super(ModelBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        fields = []
        # Add all fields defined for the model into "fields".
        for key, value in attrs.items():
            if isinstance(value, Field):
                # Store the name of the model property.
                value.name = key
                # This ensures the list is sorted based on the creation order
                fields.insert(bisect(fields, value), value)
        # In Django, "_meta" is an "Options" object and contains both a
        # "local_fields" and a "many_to_many_fields" property. We'll use a
        # dictionary with a "fields" key to keep things simple.
        klass._meta = { 'fields': fields }
        return klass

class Model(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModelBase
```

Now let's define some example models:

```
class Model1(Model):
    a = Field()
    b = Field()
    c = Field()
    z = Field()

class Model2(Model):
    c = Field()
    z = Field()
    b = Field()
    a = Field()
```

And let's test them:

```
>>>> [f.name for f in Model1()._meta['fields']]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'z']
>>>> [f.name for f in Model2()._meta['fields']]
['c', 'z', 'b', 'a']
```

Hope this helps clarify anything that wasn't already clear in Will's answer.

Comment: Your solution should be updated to python 3.x, where `cmp()` seems to be gone. Define `__lt__()` rather than `__cmp__()`. Other than that, thanks!

Comment: And metaclass definition should be done like this: `class Model(metaclass=ModelBase)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
class SchemaItem():
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.item = item
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.order = datetime.now()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Item = %s, Order = %s"%(self.item, self.order)

class DefiningClass():
    B       = SchemaItem("B")
    C       = SchemaItem("C")
    A       = SchemaItem("A")
    PRODUCT = SchemaItem("PRODUCT")
    ASSSET  = SchemaItem("ASSET")
    TENOR   = SchemaItem("TENOR")

    def get_schema(self):
        self_class = self.__class__
        attributes = [x for x in dir(self_class) if x not in ["class","name","schema","values"]]
        schema     = [(attribute_name,getattr(self_class,attribute_name)) for attribute_name in attributes if isinstance(getattr(self_class,attribute_name),SchemaItem)]
        return dict(schema)

# Actual usage
ss = [(name,schema_item) for name,schema_item in s.get_schema().items()]
print "Before = %s" % ss
ss.sort(key=lambda a:a[1].order)
print "After =%s" % ss
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't track the order of the addition of the class variables. These attributes (as well as attributes on objects) are stored internally as a dictionary, which is optimized for fast lookups and does not support ordering.

You can see this fact:

```
class A(object):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0

A.__dict__.items()

#  [('__module__', '__main__'), 
#   ('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>), 
#   ('y', 0), ('x', 0), ('z', 0), 
#   ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>), 
#   ('__doc__', None)]
```

If you want your attributes in a particular order, you could just add another field, containing this information:

```
class B(object):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    a = 0
    _ordering = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']

print B._ordering
# => ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']
```

Sidenote: In python 2.7 and 3.2 ordered dictionaries will be introduced as part of the standard library.

Comment: It's not bad but don't conform to DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

Django's model and form metaclasses work together with the field descriptors to maintain the original order. There is no way of doing what you ask without jumping through a *lot* of hoops. See the Django source code if you're still interested.

Answer (score 1):

For now just use Python 3.6!

```
class OrderedClass():
    x = 0
    z = 0
    a = 0
    b = 0

print(list(OrderedClass.__dict__))
```

This outputs me:

> `['__module__', 'x', 'z', 'a', 'b', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']`

Comment: That's because PEP 520