# How to read class attributes in the same order as declared?

Tags: python, class, metaclass

I am writing a metaclass that reads class attributes and store them in a list, but I want the list (cls.columns) to respect the declaration order (that is: `mycol2`, `mycol3`, `zut`, `cool`, `menfin`, `a` in my example):

```
import inspect
import pprint

class Column(object):
    pass

class ListingMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        cls = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)
        cls.columns = inspect.getmembers(cls, lambda o: isinstance(o, Column)) 
        cls.nb_columns = len(cls.columns)
        return cls

class Listing(object):
    __metaclass__ = ListingMeta
    mycol2 = Column()
    mycol3 = Column()
    zut = Column()
    cool = Column()
    menfin = Column()
    a = Column()

pprint.pprint(Listing.columns)
```

Result:

```
[('a', <__main__.Column object at 0xb7449d2c>),
 ('cool', <__main__.Column object at 0xb7449aac>),
 ('menfin', <__main__.Column object at 0xb7449a8c>),
 ('mycol2', <__main__.Column object at 0xb73a3b4c>),
 ('mycol3', <__main__.Column object at 0xb744914c>),
 ('zut', <__main__.Column object at 0xb74490cc>)]
```

This does not respect the declaration order of `Column()` attributes for `Listing` class. If I use `classDict` directly, it does not help either.

How can I proceed?

Comment: I don't think you can get them in order without some sort of source-level analysis. In any case, the order is supposed to be mostly irrelevant. The `dict` hashes by key, which is why you're not seeing it in order

Comment: At all, a very constructive question. thanks

Comment: you can take a look on tosca widget 2, to find how to do that

Answer (score 40):

In the current version of Python, the class ordering is preserved.  See [PEP520](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520/) for details.

In older versions of the language (3.5 and below, but not 2.x), you can provide a metaclass which uses an `OrderedDict` for the class namespace.

```
import collections 

class OrderedClassMembers(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(self, name, bases):
        return collections.OrderedDict()

    def __new__(self, name, bases, classdict):
        classdict['__ordered__'] = [key for key in classdict.keys()
                if key not in ('__module__', '__qualname__')]
        return type.__new__(self, name, bases, classdict)

class Something(metaclass=OrderedClassMembers):
    A_CONSTANT = 1

    def first(self):
        ...

    def second(self):
        ...

print(Something.__ordered__)
# ['A_CONSTANT', 'first', 'second']
```

**This approach doesn't help you with existing classes, however, where you'll need to use introspection.**

Comment: Any ideas or pointers as how to use and learn about *introspection*? (Or better, how to apply it in this case.)

Comment: It should also be noted that even in P3.6 the order is not always retained when using external classes to help define the *Something* class items.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the workaround I juste developped :

```
import inspect

class Column(object):
    creation_counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.creation_order = Column.creation_counter
        Column.creation_counter+=1

class ListingMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        cls = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)
        cls.columns = sorted(inspect.getmembers(cls,lambda o:isinstance(o,Column)),key=lambda i:i[1].creation_order) 
        cls.nb_columns = len(cls.columns)
        return cls

class Listing(object):
    __metaclass__ = ListingMeta
    mycol2 = Column()
    mycol3 = Column()
    zut = Column()
    cool = Column()
    menfin = Column()
    a = Column()


for colname,col in Listing.columns:
    print colname,'=>',col.creation_order
```

Comment: First I thought "You must reset the creation_counter after each class", and then I realized that you don't at all, assuming you only care about the internal order. It actually works. :)

Comment: How it working in parallel threads ? i think this code is not threadsafe.

Comment: For Python3.6+ refer to @Conchylicultor answer, which is likely based on newer dict order insertion guarantees by the language.  You can use `vars(cls)` rather than the uglier `cls.__dict__`.

Answer (score 16):

For python 3.6, this has become the default behavior. See PEP520: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520/

```
class OrderPreserved:
    a = 1
    b = 2
    def meth(self): pass

print(list(OrderPreserved.__dict__.keys()))
# ['__module__', 'a', 'b', 'meth', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
```

Answer (score 8):

1) Since Python 3.6 attributes in a class definition have the same order in which the names appear in the source. This order is now preserved in the new class’s `__dict__` attribute (https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep520):

```
class Column:
    pass

class MyClass:
    mycol2 = Column()
    mycol3 = Column()
    zut = Column()
    cool = Column()
    menfin = Column()
    a = Column()

print(MyClass.__dict__.keys())
```

You will see output like this (`MyClass.__dict__` may be used like OrderedDict):

```
dict_keys(['__module__', 'mycol2', 'mycol3', 'zut', 'cool', 'menfin', 'a', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__'])
```

Note extra  `__xxx__` fields added by python, you may need to ignore them.

2) For previous **Python 3.x** versions you can use solution based on by @Duncan answer, but simpler.
We use that fact, that `__prepare__` method returns a `OrderDict` instead of simple `dict` - so all attributes gathered before `__new__` call will be ordered.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedClass(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases): 
         return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
        result.__fields__ = list(classdict.keys())
        return result

class Column:
    pass

class MyClass(metaclass=OrderedClass):
    mycol2 = Column()
    mycol3 = Column()
    zut = Column()
    cool = Column()
    menfin = Column()
    a = Column()
```

Now you can use attribute `__fields__` for accessing attributes in required order:

```
m = MyClass()
print(m.__fields__)
['__module__', '__qualname__', 'mycol2', 'mycol3', 'zut', 'cool', 'menfin', 'a']
```

Note that there will be attrs `'__module__'`, `'__qualname__'` born from `type` class. To get rid of them you may filter names in following manner (change `OrderedClass.__new__`):

```
def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
    result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
    exclude = set(dir(type))
    result.__fields__ = list(f for f in classdict.keys() if f not in exclude)
    return result
```

it will give only attrs from MyClass:

```
['mycol2', 'mycol3', 'zut', 'cool', 'menfin', 'a']
```

3) **this anwser is only workable in python3.x, because there is no `__prepare__` definition in python2.7**

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Python 2.x then you'll need a hack such as the one Lennart proposes. If you are using Python 3.x then read [PEP 3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) as that contains an example which does what you want. Just modify the example to only look at your Column() instances:

```
 # The custom dictionary
 class member_table(dict):
    def __init__(self):
       self.member_names = []

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
       # if the key is not already defined, add to the
       # list of keys.
       if key not in self:
          self.member_names.append(key)

       # Call superclass
       dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

 # The metaclass
 class OrderedClass(type):

     # The prepare function
     @classmethod
     def __prepare__(metacls, name, bases): # No keywords in this case
        return member_table()

     # The metaclass invocation
     def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        # Note that we replace the classdict with a regular
        # dict before passing it to the superclass, so that we
        # don't continue to record member names after the class
        # has been created.
        result = type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))
        result.member_names = classdict.member_names
        return result

 class MyClass(metaclass=OrderedClass):
    # method1 goes in array element 0
    def method1(self):
       pass

    # method2 goes in array element 1
    def method2(self):
       pass
```

Answer (score 4):

An answer that excludes methods:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from types import FunctionType


class StaticOrderHelper(type):
    # Requires python3.
    def __prepare__(name, bases, **kwargs):
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        namespace['_field_order'] = [
                k
                for k, v in namespace.items()
                if not k.startswith('__') and not k.endswith('__')
                    and not isinstance(v, (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod))
        ]
        return type.__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)


class Person(metaclass=StaticOrderHelper):
    first_name = 'First Name'
    last_name = 'Last Name'
    phone_number = '000-000'

    @classmethod
    def classmethods_not_included(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def staticmethods_not_included(self):
        pass

    def methods_not_included(self):
        pass


print(Person._field_order)
```

Comment: This also works for using [imported Scrapy items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714584/how-to-import-scrapy-item-keys-in-the-correct-order/) when they are assigned in a class with `some_item = Field()`.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you should be able to make a class where you replace its `__dict__` with an `ordered-dict`

Comment: Nice idea. have you tested it ?

Comment: I tried but it turned out to be not in `defined order`