# Using the SQLAlchemy ORM, how can I get the nth column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have created a table via SQLAlchemy's declarative system.

```
class Recipe (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text)
    instructions = Column(Text)
```

Let's now assume I perform a query which yields an instance `r` of the `Recipe` class. How can I get `r`'s `n`th column value? (e.g. express `r.instructions` as something like `r[2]` -- which doesn't work.)

Comment: What determines the order of the columns?

Comment: I thought I did by the order I was specifying the class members. Isn't that the case?

Comment: The way the question is worded, we could only assume that that was the case. So, since that is what you're looking for, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459531/how-to-read-class-attributes-in-the-same-order-as-declared).

Comment: I hoped my example would make that clear, but I see that it was by no means nonambiguous. Anyway, thanks for the link; though that workaround specified there is a bit more complex than I hoped I needed. Isn't there anything SQLAlchemy specific that I can use to make it simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found something:

```
getattr(r, list(Recipe.__table__._columns)[n].name)
```

`Recipe.__table__columns` returns what looks like a list but is actually an `ImmutableColumnCollection`. So we use `list` to turn it into one, and take that list's `n`th element's name -- the column name (so for `n == 2`, that would be `instructions`). Finally, we `getattr` the attribute of that name from our `Recipe` object, `r`.