# Reading order of declared members in Python class without using metaclasses

Tags: python, python-2.7, reflection

Important notes to avoid too fast/invalid duplicate tagging - please read it before answer.

*Please **do not suggest any solution changing original class code** - reflection and parsing without changing code is allowed.*

1. *[How to read class attributes in the same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459531/how-to-read-class-attributes-in-the-same-order-as-declared) is not a solution - it requires to replace meta class in all classes and add overhead - definitely it is not reflection use.*
2. *Consider that I can not or do not want change code to scan class members order. Classes can have or has unknown metaclasses already - it is not possible to just add metaclass or add performance overhead without reason.*
3. *Only reflection can be used or parsing files.*

---

I want to avoid writing parser and read class attributes in order of declaration.

How **it is possible with use reflection** in Python if it possible at all.

Let me give some example:

```
class A(object):
  b = 1
  a = 1
  c = 1
```

`dir(A)` give alphabetic order but required is declaration order. How to do it - please help?

Comment: Can you show duplicate before marking?

Comment: The duplicate link is listed at the top of this page.

Comment: It is not solution since it require to replace metaclass in all classes which have allready some metaclasses - it is not works.