# Reading class attributes in the same order as declared in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

I am developing some code that requires access to attributes of a class in the same order that they were declared. I have found the following answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460034 however as it was mentioned in the comment, it is not threads safe. I am using Python 2.7. I am wondering if there is a way to force python using OrderedDict when collecting attributes?

The actual use case is to have an ability to define Structs like it is done here (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498149/), but the solution should be thread safe.

Comment: You could just use `__slots__` in your class, I imagine.

Comment: To me this sounds like [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes you can, there are a few related questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact problem has a solution in **Python3** using a metaclass. It's described in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).

However, it uses the `__prepare__` classmethod, which is not available in Python2.7. After some googling I did find [this solution](https://gist.github.com/DasIch/5562625) that ports `__prepare__` to Python2.7, but it's incredibly hacky and dirty.

To me it sounds like you're having the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and your problem can be solved through a different approach.

Comment: @orip Thanks, [Mentioned solution](https://gist.github.com/DasIch/5562625) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @pigeek If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. This helps future users, and gives both me and you a bit of reputation. Also, it's ORLP, not ORIP ;)